# Static variable in JavaScript class throws an error in Chrome 70

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, es6-class, static-variables

Consider:

```
class Welcome{
   static name="something"; // Throws an error
}
```

[MDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MDN_Web_Docs) says `static` will be supported from Chrome 42. But it is throwing a syntax error in Chrome 70 and below versions.

Comment: [CanIUse says version 72](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_classes_static_class_fields). Seems the MDN browser data is off.

Comment: @VLAZ [MDN says 72 as well](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields#browser_compatibility). It's [`static` method syntax in `class`es](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static#browser_compatibility) that was introduced with chrome 42

Comment: WTH are you using a  Chrome browser that's over 4 years old?

Comment: @Bergi Probably an unfortunate web developer having to support legacy browsers?

Comment: @InSync I've seen many a legacy environment, but none with legacy Chrome

Comment: @Bergi Kiosks :( Only had it happen once, but kiosks are annoying sometimes.

Comment: I've never been told that I have to support an out of support version of any evergreen browser (something that should update automatically). If I had been though, I would push back and say that even the browser vendor won't support the browser so why should I. Of course though, your mileage may vary with this.

Answer (score 2):

> MDN says static will be supported from Chrome 42.

MDN Web Docs does not paint a detailed picture [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static#browser_compatibility), as this article deals with static class methods, static blocks and static class fields. Support for these different uses of `static` did not all come in Chrome version 42. The support for static class *fields* came later. On the MDN Web Docs page dedicated to [Public class fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields#browser_compatibility) it mentions Chrome version 72:

> [image]

If a browser doesn't have support for static class fields, you can use this code instead:

```
function defineStaticField(cls, prop, value) {
    Object.defineProperty(cls, prop, { 
        value, 
        writable: true,
        configurable: true,
        enumerable: true,
    });
}

class Welcome{
}

defineStaticField(Welcome, "name", "something");
```

Comment: …or really just `Welcome.name = "something"` (well, maybe for [anything else but `name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name))

Comment: That's the thing: their example was with `name`.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, you can use a [transpiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler) like [Babel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babel_(transcompiler)).

Transpilers convert code written in newer versions of JavaScript into an older, more widely supported syntax.